# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.PersistenceContext

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Можно, пожалуйста, пошагово, а то не совсем понимаю как сделать.

Ошибка:

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.<init>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:671)

The following method did not exist:

    'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'

The method's class, javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/IdeaProjects/apis/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_2.2_spec/1.0/geronimo-jpa_2.2_spec-1.0.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/IdeaProjects/apis/lib/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.PersistenceContext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дорогие друзья, мне никто не помог, но я действовал исходя из своей логики.
Ещё раз посмотрите как у меня выглядел этот момент:

he method's class, javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, is available from the following locations:

> ```
> jar:file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/IdeaProjects/apis/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
> jar:file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_2.2_spec/1.0/geronimo-jpa_2.2_spec-1.0.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
> jar:file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
> ```
>
> It was loaded from the following location:
>
> ```
> file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/IdeaProjects/apis/lib/javax.persistence.jar
> ```

Я просто исходя из логики подумал, что maven важнее и удалил из lib, вот по этому пути удалил:

```
 file:/C:/Users/vladislav.gilenko/IdeaProjects/apis/lib/javax.persistence.jar
```

У меня всё заработало, эта ошибка связана с тем, что idea немного путается и не понимает какую версию нужно брать, происходит ошибка из-за разных версий программы. Это мне помогло: [ссылка](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14040).